# Flutter - How to dynamically add height value of a container before loading the UI?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have added a `setState` Method inside the `build` widget after getting my data from API response via StreamBuilder. But it gives this error:

> Unhandled Exception: `setState()` or `markNeedsBuild()` called during build.

How do I avoid this situation?

My code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.getData,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Home> dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.hasData) {
            if (dataSnapshot.data.description != null) _expandHeightBy(40); 
            ........
```

Function

```
      _expandHeightBy(double increase) async {
    setState(() {
      _expandedHeightVal += increase;
    });
  }
```

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: As shown in the `StreamBuilder` @CodePoet

Comment: Ah yes, obviously, sorry. Just wondering if you do the same without setState() as you are building the UI, you don't need it I guess. Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the `setState` from the method calling as @CodePoet suggested and it actually worked fine.

```
     _expandHeightBy(double increase) {
       _expandedHeightVal += increase;
     }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call setState during build, and for good reason. setState runs the build method. Therefore if you were able to call setState in build, it would infinitely loop the build method since it essentially calls itself.

Check out this article. It has an example of conditionally rendering based on a StreamBuilder. https://medium.com/@sidky/using-streambuilder-in-flutter-dcc2d89c2eae